# Invalidate() function not working

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a function that checks whenever a button check box i clicked

```
void CRisanjeDlg::OnBnClickedCheck1()
{
    Invalidate(1);
}
```

And in the OnPaint method i have this code:

```
    if(m_CheckBox1.GetState() ==1 )
{
    CBrush brush;
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,200,255));
    rect.DeflateRect(0,0,500,0);
    dc.Rectangle(rect);
    dc.FillRect(rect, &brush);
}
```

I have a couple of other events, which trigger the OnPaint method, and if the box is checked, it draws what it has to draw.

It just doesn't work when i click the check box. The event is recognized, it's just that the Invalidate(1) does not work...

Any suggestions?

EDIT: When I uncheck the box, the function works fine. It seems the problem should be in the

```
if(m_CheckBox1.GetState() ==1 )
```

part.

EDIT2: True, the problem was in the mentioned if statement. This fixed it, don't know why. Would appreciate a further explanation.

```
m_CheckBox1.GetCheck() ==1
```

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate(); UpdateWindow(); ?

Comment: Regarding your second edit, to see if a checkbox is checked, you can use GetState, but you have to mask it with BST_CHECKED (which is 0x0001). Otherwise, you are getting the pushed and focused state too, and that won't equal 1, since it will be focused because you have just clicked it. So you should do `if(m_CheckBox1.GetState() & BST_CHECKED)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the debugger and see if you are coming inside your OnBnClickedCheck1 function

Comment: Does it come inside the Paint function too? And if yes, inside your if statement too?

Comment: Yes it does. As I said "I have a couple of other events, which trigger the OnPaint method, and if the box is checked, it draws what it has to draw.", it just doesnt work when I click the check button.

Comment: IIRC, OnPaint won't be fired until all other messages in the message queue have been processed, so you won't see an immediate change.

Comment: Well what does that mean? I have a small app, and the queue should be processed all the time. It just doesn't trigger when I check it. When I check the button, the Invalidate() function is called.

Answer (score 1):

`GetState` returns a *combination* of states. Since the user is pressing on the button, you'll have `BST_PUSHED` and `BST_FOCUS` in addition to `BST_CHECKED`. It would have worked if you just tested for the single bit:

```
if ((m_CheckBox1.GetState() & BST_CHECKED) == BST_CHECKED)
```

Which can be simplified, since any non-zero value is true:

```
if (m_CheckBox1.GetState() & BST_CHECKED)
```